# How to make Young tableau of different shapes aligned in an equation?

Tags: latex3, ytableau

I am attempting to typeset an equation that includes a sequence of Young tableaux with varying shapes, using the ytableau package in LaTeX. My objective is to align these tableaux neatly while having the relation symbol `\succeq` centered between them.

he challenge is the `\succeq` symbols do not center properly with tableaux of different heights. How can I ensure that the \succeq is always perfectly centered both horizontally and vertically between each tableau? Is there a particular command or package that could facilitate this alignment?

My code is

```
\begin{aligned}
    \ydiagram{4,2,2,1}\succeq \ydiagram{4,2,1}\succeq \ydiagram{4,2,1}\succeq \ydiagram{3,1}\succeq \ydiagram{2}
\end{aligned}
```

and the look is

[image]

I want the equation looks like this

[image]

I would be grateful for any tips or solutions to this typesetting issue.

Comment: Please apply this procedure/checklist on your code snippet and improve your code to be posted. Thank you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137

Answer (score 2):

You want `centertableaux`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\begin{document}

\[
\ytableausetup{centertableaux}
\ydiagram{4,2,2,1}\succeq \ydiagram{4,2,1}\succeq \ydiagram{4,2,1}
\succeq \ydiagram{3,1}\succeq \ydiagram{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that if you don't want the same alignment later, you need to reset the alignment, because options for tableaux are global.

[image]

Comment: I see. Thank you!